# What collection should I use in this case?

Tags: c#, collections

I'm writing a class to store some kind of a table-structure.

Now each column in this table structure has a name, and an index.

Now each row in this column will be looped through, and the data will 90% of the cases be requested using the name of the column rather then the index of it.

So what's a good data structure to store the columns, so that it can retrieve the index very quickly based upon the name. Right now I'm using a simple string[], but I wonder if there are faster ways to do this.

Parts of the code:

```
private string[] _columns;
private int _width;

private int getIndex(string columnName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _width; i++)
    {
        if (_columns[i] == columnName) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The names of the columns will be constant after they've been set, and they're mostly about 10-16 characters long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: I thought dictionary was used to store data by a key, while this is the other way around. Anyways I'll benchmark it.

Comment: How often are you going to be adding/removing stuff from the collection?

Comment: I quote from my own question: <quote>The names of the columns will be constant after they've been set.</quote>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<string,int>` to store the names of the columns against their ID.

Using your example (which misses how `_columns` is populated):

```
private IDictionary<string,int> _columns;
private int _width;

private int getIndex(string columnName)
{
    return _columns[columnName];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how it's populated, since it's a fixed length array, but if you want to know, it's a for(int i = 0; i < _width; i++) _columns[i] = GetColumnName(i);

Comment: @Aidiakapi - never said I wanted to know, just that you (and therefor I) did not show it.

Comment: Thanks, after running benchmarks it came down to 14760ms for the dictionary, and 23225ms for the string array. _(Looking up 100000000 times, two different values each time.)_ Though the creating of the dictionary takes 6166ms, while the string array only takes 754ms _(created 10000000 times)_, the columns might be requested over 10K times, while they're only set once, thanks :)

Comment: @Aidiakapi - Not surprising. Lookups will always be cheaper on a fixed array than a dynamic list...

Comment: Actually, the dictionary is dynamic... and the string array is fixed, yet the dictionary is almost 50% faster then the string array. Just the creation process is almost 9 times as long with the dictionary, as with the string array.

Comment: @Aidiakapi - Sorry, misread your comment... The inserts do tend to be more expensive due to the dictionary needing to expand. If you know the size of the dictionary in advance you can use the constructor that takes the capacity in order to avoid this overhead.

Comment: I did use that, I set the capacity at start, that resulted in 8911ms for creating the dictionary. But the dictionary makes use of some hashing I think, to lookup values faster then even a raw array, that probably takes some extra time.

Comment: @Oded And that's why it's faster, and that why I'm using it now :). And that extra creation time is once, that extra lookup time, especially in big "tables", can get a little bit extremely slow.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are usually going to access columns by the name, this sounds like a good place to use a Map (Dictionary class in C#) that maps Strings to Columns (String arrays).  That would allow O(1) access for the name rather than the current O(n) in the above code.

The disadvantage is that you wouldn't be able to access directly by column index anymore.  However, this is simple to solve--just keep your list of column names and use those to index!  You can then call

```
_columnsMap[_columns[index]]
```

if you ever need to index by number, and it is still O(1) time.

Comment: Good explanation why, but I'm afraid the other dude's answer is just a little bit better, thanks anyways :) +1